# Android Intent to Google Home Broadcast

Tags: android, google-home

I need to know if anyone has found a solution on how to communicate between my android application and google home broadcast to play an audio generated by me.

Thank you!

I expect that everyone response me how to solve this problem.
I've already done communication from android to googlr home app but no way from android to google home broadcast faction

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the broadcast feature on Google Home and Nest speakers and displays. When you broadcast a message, it plays on all of your Google Nest and Home devices. More information about the different kinds of broadcasting arrangement can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7531913?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cwhat-you-need).